# Pass argument to dygraph drawcallback

Tags: javascript, canvas, dygraphs

The dygraph drawcallback gets two arguments one the reference to the dygraph object and other being a boolean if its the first time the graphs being drawn.
But I also want to send optional arguments to the callback instead of creating global variables. Is that possible?

Comment: A code snippet would be helpful. You can do this using a closure or by stuffing the variables into the dygraph object.

Comment: Please provide some code so we have something to work with...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not specific to dygraphs. Rather, this is a common need when using JavaScript.  Common techniques:

**JavaScript (closure)**

---

```
var self = this;
drawCallback : function(dygraph, is_init) {
  self._myCallbackFunction(extraParam1, extraParam2, dygraph, is_init)
}
```

The `this` context might not be what you expect in your callback function though. If you want to set `this` to the context of the object where the callback function is defined, then you can use:

**JavaScript `call` or `apply` functions**

---

```
drawCallback : function(dygraph, is_init) {
  self._myCallbackFunction.call(self, extraParam1, extraParam2, dygraph, is_init)
}
```

or 
**jQuery (.proxy)**

---

```
drawCallback : $.proxy(this._myCallbackFunction, this, extraParam1, extraParam2)
```